# Approximation of positive right-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:(0, +\infty)\to(0, +\infty) $ be a **monotone decreasing**, **right-continuous** function. Can we find a sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of **strictly monotone decreasing**, **continuous functions**, such that $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $f$, that is, $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(x)$ for all $x\in (0, +\infty)?$ To achieve strict monotonicity is trivial, but I have problems with the continuity. I came across this question while reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517134/convergence-of-generalized-inverses) about convergence of generalized inverse functions.

[Edit]: Additional question: Is it possible to also make $\{f_{n}\}$ a sequence of positive functions?

[Edit]: Additional question two: Is it possible to make $\{f_{n}\}$ an increasing sequence of positive functions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sure one can! Define $D = \{(x,y) : y < f(x)\}$ and consider $D_t = \{(x,y) : (x + t y, y + t x) \in D\}$. Then it is not very difficult to see that $D_t = \{(x, y) : y < f_t(x)\}$ for a continuous, strictly decreasing function $f_t$, and $f_t(x)$ increases to $f(x)$ as $t \to 0^+$.

Comment: (I realise the above works for $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb R$, and needs an appropriate adjustment for $f : (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f_n(x) =n\int_{x}^{x+1/n} f(t) dt-x/n$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! On which domain is this function defined? It seems to be like a part of a composed function.

Comment: On $(0,\infty)$, the $-x/n$ part is just for strict monotonicity

Comment: How can strictly monotonic function have compact support?!

Comment: Is it possible to make $\{f_{n}\}$ a sequence of positive functions?

Comment: Of course, replace $-x/n$ to $+1/(nx+n)$

Comment: It is still strictly decreasing, right?

Comment: Yes, it still is

Comment: Ok thank you very very much!

Comment: But now this sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ is a decreasing sequence, is it possible that it is still an increasing sequence?